# Using GDALwarp with not-to-scale maps

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

(This question was asked on another forum 3 months ago but received no response.  I'd really welcome some help getting over the problem)

My input map is a JPG scan of a not-to-scale map. I would like to warp it to EPSG:3857 so that it can forced to scale. The result is not warping as I'd expect.  Se images below.

The approach taken is to add 9 widely dispersed GCPs (ground control points) but no projection to a new TIF file. The GCPs have been added as X, Y, Longitide, Latitude, Z=0. gdal_edit does this step (from Python) without error and gdalinfo in.tif now shows:

```
    Size is 3421, 1925
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection =
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (462,111) -> (-1.541,50.759,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (732,657) -> (-1.496,50.704,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (1998,1764) -> (-1.285,50.588,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (1911,687) -> (-1.291,50.701,0)
GCP[  4]: Id=5, Info=
          (1896,108) -> (-1.3,50.762,0)
GCP[  5]: Id=6, Info=
          (2691,360) -> (-1.158,50.732,0)
GCP[  6]: Id=7, Info=
          (2739,1098) -> (-1.149,50.659,0)
GCP[  7]: Id=8, Info=
          (3108,756) -> (-1.084,50.689,0)
GCP[  8]: Id=9, Info=
          (2163,1320) -> (-1.254,50.635,0)
```

The subsequent warp command is supposed to introduce a spatial reference system:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -t_srs EPSG:3857 in.tif out-warped-3857.tif
```

It runs, but the resulting map is stretched wrongly, from 3421x1925 to 3852x1381. Changing the output projection to EPSG:4326, the result is identical which I wouldn't expect.

There are three images to illustrate:

Reference map (OpenTopoMap)
[image]

Input map
[image]

Output map
[image]

Questions: Is this the best way to add projection and force a map to scale?
Why is the vertical dimension shrinking so much?

Comment: If you want to change the projection you must tell what is the original coordinate system in which the ground control points are. `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 in.tif out-warped-3857.tif` should make difference.

Comment: @user30184.  It seems to work - thank you. The GCPs came from Google Earth (epsg:4326) but, given that the source map was not projected as epsg:4326, I didn't realise I needed to supply that as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

When ground control points are added into a GeoTIFF with GDAL there is no information about the coordinate system yet. It can be noticed from the gdalinfo report that shows the Coordinate System as empty.

```
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection =
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (462,111) -> (-1.541,50.759,0)
```

What is known is just that pixel `(462,111)` is located in coordinates `(-1.541,50.759,0)` in some coordinate system.

Successful re-projection with gdalwarp requires that both the source CRS (`-s_srs`) and target CRS (`-t_srs`) are known. If CRS is stored into the source data gdalwarp reads it automatically and therefore the `-s_srs` parameter is not mandatory. If source data has no CRS and user does not give `-s_srs` then it is assumed that `-s_srs=-t_srs`. That's why the result with only `-t_srs` parameter looked identical for both EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857.

The gdalwarp command for converting a GeoTIFF with ground control points measured in EPSG:4326 into normal georeferenced image in EPSG:3857 is:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 in.tif out-warped-3857.tif
```